# What is the part of the speech of “But” in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions, parts-of-speech, prepositional-phrases

> “These commands are binding on all  children; they cannot be neglected without sin. Whatever God has commanded us to do, we must perform, without calling in question the propriety of the command.
>
> But the reasonableness of this command to obey parents is clear and easily understood by children, even when quite young.”

(The word “But” is a start of the new paragraph according to the sentence above. “Reasonableness” is a noun, so should it be preposition or conjunction? Because “but” could be preposition or conjunction...For me, I think it is a preposition...I’m not sure)

Comment: _But_ is always a conjunction. It refers back to the previous sentence(s), and implies that there is something surprising about the ability of children to learn even while young.

Comment: See the last page of [this](https://www.chompchomp.com/terms/coordinatingconjunction.htm).

Comment: Or in modern grammar a 'coordinator'.

Comment: @John Lawler Yes; I've so far resisted the temptation to include 'but' in my list of ditransitive-like-verbs (_But me no buts_).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The ditransitivish verbs that don't undergo Dative Movement, like _ask_?

Comment: @JohnLawler *But is always a conjunction.* "None but the brave deserve the fair."

Comment: The "but" that occurs in constructions like the OP's is of course always a coordinator, as JL says. To cite the other categories that it can belong to is off-topic.

Comment: @BillJ With all due respect to John Lawler, correction is *never* off-topic.